# how can i avoid this error with a trigger i've made it but the DBMS lost it?

Tags: oracle, plsql

there

I've made a trigger that automatically insert a random password of 5 char and num 
to any new hired police man

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER POLICE_NO_TRIGG_11111
BEFORE INSERT ON police
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT dbms_random.string('x', 5)
INTO   :new.password
FROM   dual;
END;
```

trigger created

then, i went to the form bulider, unfortunatly, unable to insert, see pic
[image]

I went back to the sql command, this is what happened
see pic

[image]

any help please!

see this for disc police table for further info
[image]

Comment: What is your table structure? In the screenshot, the column types are not visible.

Comment: see updated photo

Comment: While in a form, when you get the error message (that it is unable to insert a record), go to Help menu and choose **display error** - it'll give you some additional info. What does it say? Also, what happens when you try to manually add a row into the table (from SQL*Plus)? Finally, as USER_NAME is the only NOT NULL column, is it set to be a database item in a form?

Comment: to be honest, I don't know what exactly happened with the trigger, all that I did after reviewing all the answers here is to again apply the command of replacing or creating the trigger with the same function.

Comment: seems to me to that the database has lost the trigger, maybe it happened because I didn't commit the trigger or the connection has been lost while or after the trigger has been created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your trigger is invalid. The trigger code seems fine to me, without knowing the table definition.

You probably find some information when executing

```
select * from user_errors where type = 'TRIGGER' and name = 'POLICE_NO_TRIGG_11111';
```

If this doesn't help, maybe you find f[urther information here.](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_04098_trigger_string_string_is_invalid_and_failed_re_validation.htm)